# Configure symfony2 automatic form label generation

Tags: forms, symfony, sonata-admin

I'd like to know if there is a way to configure, disable or otherwise override the way Symfony handles automatically generating form labels for entity properties.

We also use the Sonata Admin Bundle and Symfony native and Sonata do not always produce the same label for complex form fields based on a given entity property, specifically when adding related entity properties e.g. something.somethingRelated.  Sometimes it seems there is an extra space added to the label string (where the "dot" is) so we end up with two different labels being generated for the exact same property in two different forms.

Sonata has a configuration that allows some control over how the label is generated; e.g underscores, native, do nothing, etc.
We are trying to get our translations under control but still use the automatic generation of form labels rather than having to add a label (key) to each form field.

Right now I think my best alternative is to just turn it off in Symfony and let the actual property name be the "string" that is generated without any processing on it.  So, thisIsTheProperty would have an automatically generated label string "thisIsTheProperty", not "This Is The Property" or whatever.

Comment: I answered, but I think a little prematurely.  Just to get it straight, you want to use the automatic label generation, but it seems to be producing unreliable results for you at present, yes?

Comment: AND - when you say that you're still getting your translations under control - what is it you're having problems with there?  Is it the fact that your having trouble getting a reliable 'key' for your translations?

Comment: @Ragdata to your 1st question: yes, unreliable results between Symfony and Sonata.  To your 2nd question: Yes for automatic form labels, I want to have reliable names which I will use as keys for translation.  Having the key (and the label) be the property name seems to me to be the most effective way (or maybe the simplest?) to ensure that.  Not sure how it will handle related properties (something.SoemthingRelated) but as long as it is consistent, I can deal with it in the translation files.  Right now we have a translation file with lots of duplicates due to label name inconsistency.

Comment: Honestly, I think the simplest answer is adding a label (key) to each form field.  I do have another idea - but it's quite complicated and will take me a while to write up ... AND it would require that you pay close attention to the IDs of each form element (which are declared as properties of your Entities and have to be referenced in your FormType classes anyway).  The idea forces twig to render the ID (defined in part by the Entity Property Name) of each element AS a label, which you can then translate.  Do you think that would be any help?

Comment: @Ragdata, I think of the two, the "manually add a label" sounds better ;) even though that means a lot of initial "fixing" and then an additional bit of code for each form field going forward.  I was really hoping there would be a relatively simple way to just have Symfony NOT process the label, but just add whatever the property name is.

Comment: Essentially, that's what the second idea was ... but it's not straight forward.  What it would involve is extending the base 'fields.html.twig' template, replacing the `form_label` block and changing the variable which is rendered from the 'label' to the 'id' ... not a HUGE pain in the a$$ to set up and run with - but would take a bit to explain. [These docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#referencing-base-form-blocks-twig-specific) cover the basics of what I'm talking about ... hopefully they'll give you some ideas.

Comment: @Ragdata thanks for your time, I appreciate it.  I had looked at the themeing option briefly and may go that route but I fear that Sonata and Symfony use radically different approaches to the 'id' generation as well.

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with Sonata unfortunately - I avoid 3rd party bundles like the plague - but it wouldn't surprise me at all if that were indeed the case.  The themeing or manual options are the best I've got for the moment I'm sorry - but there's always at least one more way to skin a particular cat.  Best of luck with it.

Comment: @ragdata it's been a few days but if you would like to formally answer my question I'd be happy to accept it as the answer.  I ended up going with your suggestion above about the form_label. thanks!